# How to specify image as input for HTML form by using its id?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, servlets

I'm capturing photo via webcam on a web application, which would display the captured photo on screen, then send it to servlet so that I can save it directly to a path in my computer.

My problem now is I don't know how to post the photo to servlet. I googled and found some code that can upload a user-chosen file to servlet, but I need my webcam photo to be the form input *without letting user choose a file to upload*. I have the id of the photo.

**Here's what I found:**

```
<form method="post" action="UploadServlet"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="file" size="60" /><br /><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

This code integrates well with my code and everything can run, but I don't want to upload a file, I want to set the captured image as my form input so the user just have to click "submit" after seeing the image.

**Code that displays the captured photo:**

```
<div class="output"><img id="photo" alt="The image preview will appear in this box."></div>
```

The captured photo is rendered and displayed here as a PNG image. How do I make it the form input?

**JavaScript:**

```
(function() {
var width = 320;
var height = 0;    
var streaming = false;
var video = null;
var canvas = null;
var photo = null;
var startbutton = null;

function startup() {
    video = document.getElementById('video');
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    photo = document.getElementById('photo');
    var confirmPhoto = document.getElementById('photo'); 
    startbutton = document.getElementById('startbutton');

    navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    navigator.getMedia(
            {
                video: true,
                audio: false
            },
            function(stream) {
                if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
                    video.mozSrcObject = stream;
                } else {
                    var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                }
                video.play();
            },
            function(err) {
                console.log("An error occured! " + err);
            }
    );

    video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev){
        if (!streaming) {
            height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth/width);

            if (isNaN(height)) {
                height = width / (4/3);
            }

            video.setAttribute('width', width);
            video.setAttribute('height', height);
            canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
            canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
            streaming = true;
        }
    }, false);

    startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
        takepicture();
        ev.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    clearphoto();
}

function clearphoto() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    photo.setAttribute('src', data);
}

function takepicture() {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (width && height) {
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        photo.setAttribute('src', data);
    } else {
        clearphoto();
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', startup, false);})();
```

Please help! Thank you!!

Comment: [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)